# android custom view with shape and glow

Tags: android, view

I am trying to create a new custom view in android. The view is an animated circle which should support 3 statuses and the animation of transitions between them:
1. not selected - empty circle.
2. selected - full circle.
3. selected and glowing - full circle with "light" coming out of it (to some radius).
I have tried creating it the following way:
I have extended FrameLayout, and created 3 members called unselsected, selected and glow. I created 3 xml files accordingly one has an empty circle, the second has a filled circle and the third, for now also contains an full circle even though it should contain the "light".

The animations are done by the use of ObjectAnimator on the alpha. Switching between unselected and selected works great.

The two problems:
1. How do I create the "light"?
2. The size of the circles is always determined by the biggest image. How do I change that?

Comment: Have you achieved it?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve it create a class ButtonView which will extend View  and it will maintain three state.
Non-selected-0, on-Pressed-1; Selected 2;

On Above state you need to draw three different circular on canvas.

If you want any demo :
please use below link:

https://github.com/markushi/android-circlebutton

call view in your xml:

```
<at.markushi.ui.CircleButton
            android:layout_width="64dip"
            android:layout_height="64dip"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_tick"
            app:cb_color="#99CC00"
            app:cb_pressedRingWidth="8dip" />
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful for problem number 1. Problem 2 was solved as I changed the way I draw the shapes.

Comment: if its helpful 4 u then please mark as right ans for other also.

Comment: This was helpful but not an actual solution to the problem. What I am trying to do is more like have light surrounding the circle. It should look as if a white lamp was turned on in it's middle and is spreading light on and around it in a circular manner that fades out. The borders should be faded, not sharp.